how to image check animation in android?
I want to check whether a photo received from Android Gallery is an animation or just a photo.
I found AnimationDrawable through a search and found out that it checks, but it always returns N.
ex image
https://bigfile.mail.naver.com/download?fid=8/RrbrCXWHM/FoujK3YZKxuXFxtjKogZFAg9KA2wKAumKAEjKxbwFqbXKoKla3YXpzMXFo+CFx30p6FSKA+0aAFSKAvXM4UlFxISKzKmFg==
val uri = Uri.parse(getPath(element.path ?: "", requireContext()))
val path = uri.path
val drawable: Drawable? = Drawable.createFromPath(path)

 if (drawable is AnimationDrawable) {
    imageGif.add(ImageData(0L, element.path!!))
    Timber.d("Test Checked Animated: Y")
 } else { 
     imageUris.add(element)
     Timber.d("Test Checked Animated: N")
}


i found miss
no AnimationDrawable
I need to use this AnimatedImageDrawable
